# Conditional Statement within HTML tags in a Javascript document

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm trying to get only the products from a specific category (category is an integer from 1-3) to appear on the product screen. When I tried to create a conditional statement `(if product.category < 2){}`) to encompass the `return();` portion of my Product.js document I get an internal server error (500 error). Now, I'm wondering if it is possible to call this conditional statement within ProductScreen.js? Specifically, I was wondering if it is possible to call this conditional statement within `<Product></Product>`  as `product.category` is not defined in the rest of the document? I would really appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you!

ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Product from '../components/Product';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';



export default function ProductScreen() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const { loading, error, products } = productList;
    useEffect(() =>{
      
        dispatch(listProducts());
     }, [dispatch]);
      
  
  return (
    <div>
        {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
      <div className="row center">
        {products.map((product ) => ( 
          <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>
        ))}
      </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Product.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Rating from './Rating';

export default function Product(props) {
  const { product } = props;
  

  

    return ( 
      <div key={product._id} className="card">
        <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
          <img className="medium" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
        </Link>
        <div className="card-body">
        <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
        </Link>
        <Rating
          rating={product.rating}
          numReviews={product.numReviews}
        ></Rating>
        <div className="price">${product.price}</div>
        <div className="category">
        {product.category}
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
        
  
};
```

productAction.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
  PRODUCT_CREATE_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_CREATE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_UPDATE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_UPDATE_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_FAIL,
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/products');
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
export const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  }; 
  export const createProduct = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_REQUEST });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post(
        '/api/products',
        {},
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        }
      );
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS,
        payload: data.product,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };
  export const updateProduct = (product) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_REQUEST, payload: product });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.put(`/api/products/${product._id}`, product, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_FAIL, error: message });
    }
  };
  export const deleteProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const {data} = Axios.delete(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_SUCCESS });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };


  export const createReview = (productId, review) => async (
    dispatch,
    getState
  ) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_REQUEST });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post(
        `/api/products/${productId}/reviews`,
        review,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        }
      );
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_SUCCESS,
        payload: data.review,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };
```

Comment: If you did literally use `if product.category < 2){}` there's a syntax error, which may have been the cause of your 500 error. `if(product.category < 2){  .. }`

Comment: No, sorry,  I used `(if product.category < 2){}`. In my question, I just made a typing error.